# Will there be a German Stack Exchange website?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, languages

I've found the web page `es.stackoverflow.com`. I'm wondering, will there come a German version of Stack Exchange too?

I'm curious, may I open a German speaking subgroup on Stack Exchange (after request on Area 51)?

Comment: I am confused - these seem to be very two different questions/requests. Can you post them separately so they can be discussed separately?

Comment: If you mean Stack Overflow (the site) whenever you say StackExchange… no, everything on SO needs to be in English (and Oded's answer covers the German SO site possibility). If you actually meant Stack Exchange proper, there already is a [German Stack Exchange](//german.stackexchange.com/), which is about the *language*, just like ELU, Japanese, and so on. As far as I know, the language sites are all dual-language, with most users expected to be at least reasonably conversant in English as well as whatever their level of skill in the topic language may be.

Comment: As an alternative you could try https://www.stacklounge.de - a new site for informatics and programming - only in German. Targetting academic and beginners, but any programming question is welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm wondering, will there come a German version of StackExchange too?

The area 51 proposal for [a Stack Overflow in German site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97379/stack-overflow-in-german) (I am assuming you are specifically asking about a Stack Overflow in German - not a "German version Stack Exchange", as I have no idea what that means) was closed as "not feasible". There are a lot of resources required to launch a site in a new language (a lot of translation work, a community manager that is fluent in English/German and that is familiar with developers and both developer and Stack Exchange cultures needs to be hired and there are probably other costs involved).

All this for the benefit of German programmers who are not able to communicate on the English Stack Overflow. Of which there are not many.

> may I open a German speaking subgroup on Stackexchange (after request on Area 51)?

How would you do that? These sites are launched by Stack Exchange, not community members. And even if you propose one, that doesn't mean it will get enough followers or that Stack Exchange will be willing to put in the effort to support a site of limited use.

Again - not sure what a "German speaking subgroup on Stackexchange" means exactly.

Comment: Incidentally, [German.SE](http://german.stackexchange.com/) (as in "a site for people learning German") exists.

Comment: But there is no https://de.stackoverflow.com

Comment: I'm not so sure about the comment "of which there are not many". I work in a team with German speakers, who can all speak English and all use Stack Overflow. However, I am pretty sure that I (a native English speaker) am the only one in the team who ever actually posts questions. There is a very natural reluctance to post questions in a foreign language, even among people who are capable of doing it.